# Setting width constraint for label on Storyboard relative to the width constraint of another label in the same stack

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, storyboard

How do I set the width constraint of my label on swift so that it is always equal to the width of another label in the same stack using the Storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl-click-drag from one label to the other.

Release mouse button.

Then select Equal Widths from the popup.